# What does multilinear function mean?

Tags: probability, terminology, linear-programming

A draft research paper claims that $Q(p)=1-p_1 p_2 p_3 p_4 - p_2 p_3 p_6 p_7-p_1p_2$ is multilinear where $p_i = \mathbb P(e_i)$ and $e_i$ is a basic event of a component to fail.

I have learnt in LP course that even a function $Q_2(p)=p_1 p_2$ is quadratic when $p_1,p_2 \in \{0,1\}$, not LP. I find the part *"linear"* confusing in the word *"multilinear"*. The claim is so that $Q(p)$ is a multilinear function. What does this *"multilinear"* mean? Is this quadratic constraint $Q_2(p)$  multilinear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, a function with several variables is called multilinear function if it's linear for each variable.

Comment: I agree.  So the function given is not multilinear.

Comment: Suppose $p_i\in[0,1]$. Now is the function $e^{p_1}$ linear where $e$ is the Euler number? What about $p_1 p_2$? Some examples and counter-examples could help...

Comment: $Q$ is not multilinear but $Q_2$ it is so we say also $Q_2$ is bilinear.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane I cannot yet understand -- why is the $Q(p)=1-p_1 p_2 p_3 p_4 - p_2 p_3 p_6 p_7-p_1p_2$ not multilinear?

Comment: Because there's the $1$, so you can check for example that $Q(p_1+p'_1,p_2,p_3,p_4)\neq Q(p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4)+Q(p'_1,p_2,p_3,p_4)$.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane if you are right, you are destroying my professor's seminar paper...can you have references for your definition? Perhaps there are different definitions for multilinearity?

Comment: I'm sorry.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_map